# Android and regex to read substring

Tags: android, regex

I'm trying to use regex in an Android application to read a substring. I'm using Pattern and Matcher, but I can't figure out how to do it.

My input string is: javascript:submitForm(document.voip_call_log,30,0,'xxxxx','',0,'');
where xxxxx is a variable number of digits.

How can I read 'xxxxx' using Pattern and Matcher?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an expert in `RegEx`, but this one should work for you:

```
String input = "javascript:submitForm(document.voip_call_log,30,0,'5555','',0,'');";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(",'(\\d*)',");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
matcher.find();
String out = matcher.group(1);
System.out.println(out);
```

Proof http://ideone.com/WI6VB1

Answer (score 0):

If you will have always that format, it might be easier to use the `split(",")` method and access the value you like.

Alternatively, you could try something like so:

```
String str = ...;
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d{3,})");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
while(m.find())
{
     System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
String s = "javascript:submitForm(document.voip_call_log,30,0,'1999','',0,'');";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("javascript:submitForm\\([^,]+,\\d*,\\d*,'(\\d+)','\\d*'");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(s);
if(m.find( )) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

This is following the pattern of your input string from the question description. You can find the explanation of your regex from [this link](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl). Just input your regex with single slash `\` instead of double `\\`